# Content Page using Master Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a site that requires users to log in. 
Logging in creates a session that redirects them to the customer home page when they click the home button (instead of taking them to the non-user home page).I do this by checking if the `session["Username"]` has a value and `session["Loggedin"]` is set to true (which only happens upon logging in).

However, I can't log out once logged in.  I think it has to do with the fact that my Log-out button is part of the customer.Master page that the customer home page inherits.  The Log out button in the master page has code behind that clears, but when I click Log out right now, it just redirects to the customer home page.  Is the master page code behind even being called?

```
public void Logout(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Contents.RemoveAll();
    Session["Loggedin"] = false;
    Session["Username"] = null;
    Response.Redirect("/Pages/Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: You can ensure the code is being called by simply placing a breakpoint. Have you tried this?

Comment: I tried, and it's not being called. What could I do to have the content page call the master page code behind? Or does it not work that way? thanks~

Comment: Create a new Web Forms project with authentication and look into how the logging out is done in the master page.

Comment: Why don't you put that code rigth into your master page's code behind ? Is the Log Out button is always visible from the customer's master page ?

Comment: This code is in the code behind of the master page, and it doesn't get called when I press log out in the content page (the log out button is part of the master page as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>To call your master page code behind from another page, you first need to reference it on your .aspx page with the following directive (substitute with the path to your master page):</s>

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/customer.master" %>
```

You should now be able to access public members on the master page from your pages like this:

```
var x = Master.myProperty;
Master.myMethod();
```

**EDIT**
Different problem: the LinkButton has an event handler, but it's also got a HRef attribute. It's moving to a new page before it gets a chance to call the code.

Comment: Where would I have "Master.myMehod();"? The linkbutton I click to log out is part of the customer.master page?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. So your LinkButton and the Logout script are both on the master page. I'm surprised that doesn't work then. What's the code of your LinkButton?

Comment: <asp:LinkButton href="/Pages/Default.aspx" onclick ="Logout" runat="server">Log Out</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: That looks ok. How about your `Response.Redirect` call... should that be virtual path instead? `~/Pages/Default.aspx`

Comment: Oh, hang on, you've got a `href` in there. What happens if you take it out? It might be redirecting before it gets a chance to call your code...

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! been working on this for 3 hours... I feel like a scrub
Can anyone tell me exactly how href and ref are different?

Comment: Never saw ref in HTML, You want the difference between a C# ref and an HTML href ?

Comment: Very different concepts, best raise a different question for that. `href` is the relevant attribute here: that's standard HTML to tell the browser what page to load when the link is clicked ('**H**ypertext **Ref**erence')

Answer (score 2):

Do not Href in your link button, it get's you out of the current page BEFORE executing the onclick event. That's why the code behind is not executed.